# Error in linsched in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, ubuntu-13.10

I'm having the following error when running linsched What is the reason?

```
ld: Warning: size of symbol `sched_clock' changed from 8 in ../../../tools/linsched/hrtimer.o to 28 in ../../../kernel/sched/clock.o
ld: Warning: size of symbol `linsched_test_main' changed from 60 in ../../../tools/linsched/test_lib.o to 287 in linsched_rand_test.o
ld: Relocatable linking with relocations from format elf64-x86-64 (../../../tools/linsched/linux_linsched.o) to format elf32-i386 (linsched_rand_test.percpu) is not supported
make[1]: *** [linsched_rand_test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mojtaba/00/tools/linsched/tests'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run it on X86_64 architecture.